# How can I get only the users (friends) who are using my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I have a PhoneGap app, where I need to list all the user's friends, who have authorized the application on Facebook.

I'm currently using `FB.api('/me/friends?fields=installed', callbackFnc)`, but this shows me **all** friends, pointing which of them have authorized the app. When I really wanted to list **only** the authorized ones.
This slows a lot the process of loading friends.

I saw other similar questions here, but none of them had the answer.

**SOLUTION: Thanks to [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe)**
I couldn't have sucess passing the FQL directly to FB.api, but only using that object:

```
var apiQuery = 
{
   method: 'fql.query',
   query: 'SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me() ) AND is_app_user'
}   

FB.api(apiQuery, function(response){...});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FQL instead:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN
  (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me() ) AND is_app_user
```

(You can set up that query against the Graph API as well, `/fql?q={query}`.)

Comment: Use FQL through GraphAPI would help a lot, I didn't know it was possible. But I tried that and had errors.  Using brackets surrounding the FQL:  {"error":{"message":"(#601) Parser error: unexpected '{' at position 0.","type":"OAuthException","code":601}}  

Not using brackets: {"error":{"message":"(#601) Parser error: unexpected '{' at position 0.","type":"OAuthException","code":601}}

Comment: FB.api("/fql?q={SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me() ) AND is_app_user}", callback);

Comment: __NO__ brackets … that was just supposed to mean put _your query in there_ … `/fql?q=SELECT …` (And now don’t come telling me that `SELECT …` gives an error as well ;-) …)

Comment: I had errors in those two cases. My first comment is very messed up, but I wrote that there. My solution was to use an object, like I edited in my question text. Thanks!

Comment: It's weird because when I get the response of this query, with console.log it shows me the results, but when I try to access to the values I doesn't return anything. Actually it's just one result, but response.data[0].name for example, it doesn't work for me :S